# ASP.NET MVC for developing widget based portals

Tags: asp.net-mvc, widget, portal

How suitable is [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) for developing anything like 
http://www.google.com/ig?

I haven't seen or failed to find any examples yet. Does the MVC approach imply that the user interface is not supposed to look like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://aspspider.info/lakkakula/local.aspx, it is Web 2.0 Portal developed using Asp.Net MVC 1.0, Microsoft Ajax Client Templates and jQuery with drag and drop widget personalization much like google.com/ig.

Comment: The link is now dead ... sad

Answer (score 3):

MVC is quite suitable for such a UI.  Your main controller can render with a list of the widgets the user has defined, or an ajax call to a method returning a JsonResult can be used... this can generate the wrappers client-side calling for each partial vie for the corresponding controls.  I would think that MVC would simplify things quite a bit.

MVC + jQueryUI would be about all you'd need...

Answer (score 0):

I guess a little bit more clarification, what exactly do you mean by "suitable"?

One method might be for each available "widgit" to be a controller, and then you can use jQuery (or whatever you want) to call the specified method and render.  The page would then have a series of "lists" (which you can store in the DB) against the user and you can simply order those lists to display the relevant widgits in the correct order.

Obviously, that's a VERY large simplification....

Comment: I guess, if it is too difficult or workarounds are not in MVC spirit we may consider ASP.Net MVC not suitable for UI like that.

Comment: Well, I've not found it to be any more difficult that any other methods.  The UI can look like anything you want it to.  You'll just need to sort out the HTML and CSS yourself.  Try this link as a start for jQuery widgit drag and drop http://labs.dropit.se/blogs/post/2009/02/24/iGoogle-Drag-and-Drop-functionality-with-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See the tutorial *[Developing Web 2.0 Portal using ASP.NET MVC, Microsoft Ajax Client Templates and jQuery with drag and drop widget personalization](http://lakkakula.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/developing-web-2-0-portal-using-asp-net-mvc-microsoft-ajax-client-templates-and-jquery-with-drag-and-drop-widget-personalization-part-1/)*.